# In C# projects, can I use Linq where I would like?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, oop

If I don't use database in C# projects, can I use `Linq` where I would like ?

Comment: LINQ is a language feature and you should be able to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From wikipedia:

> LINQ extends the language by the addition of query expressions, which
>   are akin to SQL statements, and can be used to conveniently extract
>   and process data from arrays, enumerable classes, XML documents,
>   relational databases, and third-party data sources. Other uses, which
>   utilize query expressions as a general framework for readably
>   composing arbitrary computations, include the construction of event
>   handlers[2] or monadic parsers.

So the answer is you can use linq on `arrays, enumerable classes, XML documents,
and third-party data sources`

In your case the `relational databases` is irrelevant...

Comment: Thank you very much. I would use on 'enumerable classes'.

Comment: Good luck! If any of the answers helped you, please consider marking one of them as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

> Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) is a C# language feature introduced
>   in Visual Studio 2008. Visual Studio includes LINQ provider assemblies
>   that enable the use of LINQ with **.NET Framework collections, SQL
>   Server databases, ADO.NET Datasets, and XML documents**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, LINQ to Objects defines the LINQ operator methods on `IEnumerable<T>` (as opposed to `IQueryable<T>` used by L2S / Entity Framework) and can be used by importing the `System.Linq` namespace.

See also the MSDN documentation for the [System.Linq Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)